# WPF: can't resize window without horrible visual effects

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I'm trying to learn WPF (I worked a lot with WinForms but I'm kinda new to WPF) and I have a problem when resizing my windows.
There are horrible visual effects.

Here's what's expected:
 http://data.imagup.com/12/1130871175.jpg

Here's what I get:
http://data.imagup.com/12/1130871187.jpg or http://data.imagup.com/11/1130871194.jpg

I'm not doing anything particular, even an empty window is not rendering correctly when resizing !
I do not have any problem when window is maximized.
What's the problem ?

Windows 7 32-bit / .Net 3.5 / Raden HD5850

Comment: do you have the latest drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: I agree with @JSR -- this appears to be hardware related.

Comment: Yes, I have latest drivers installed on my computer (ATI Catalyst 11.8). I do not have any other visual glitch on my machine, in any application.

Comment: I've tried turning off Aero, using 256 colors, reducing resolution...etc., nothing works >_<

Comment: Wow.  I have seen stuff like that with memory errors.  But if this is an otherwise stable PC that basically sucks.   Have you loaded VisuaStudio service packs and all service packs for Windows.   If the driver came from Microsoft I would load the drive directly from Raden.   Can you move to .NET 4.0?  At this point things cannot get worse.

Comment: It's unlikely that you would see this problem in any other apps, unless they are WPF as well.  AFAIK, WPF is the only framework that uses DirectX to render controls.  Other thing to check: make sure you're not using the "reference" video drivers from ATI, unless you bought the video card from ATI. If it's another brand with a Radeon chip on it, use the drivers from the card manufacturer. Also re-install DirectX.  But if it *is* a software problem, it's going to be hard to figure out what the problem is without seeing the XAML.

Comment: You were right. I tried moving to .Net 4.0, issue was the same. Then I downloaded a sample WPF application from random website and issue was the same. I uninstalled my latest video drivers (ATI Catalyst 11.8) and moved to previous version (11.7) and now it works fine. Looks like there are (again) terrible regressions in ATI Drivers.

Comment: these images are stale.

Comment: @sammarcow Yes, sorry, I should have used SO image system (this question is actually old for me, I didn't really know how to write good questions at this time ^^). I basically showed some glitches on resize. The one I remember is just like if the part of the window you expanded was not refreshed. Something like: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7170/6577835731_7e7cafdf87_o.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw this same issue 2 days ago on our WPF project when someone on our team updated their Catalyst drivers.

Rollback for now; hopefully they'll fix it in the next round.

Comment: That's it, I removed my latest video card drivers (ATI Catalyst 11.8) and installed the previous version (11.7), now it's fine. Thanks.