# Why is my WPF suddenly rebelling?

Tags: wpf

I've recently completed a fairly large (for one man) WPF project, and started coding something *for fun*. I was almost done with an app worthy of showing off to friends and colleagues, and I started playing with window sizes - manually resizing the window - just to see what would happen on various screens.

And what happened was - my window got corrupted for certain window sizes, especially at about 100x100 range. I got very confused, and started to remove parts from XAML, my code, everything. But the problem persisted.

Lastly, I created a brand new WPF project - I didn't even change the name - *WpfApplication1* it's called. Surely, same artifacts appear. They are more subtle than those of the app, but still clearly visible.

[image: This window intentionally left blank]

So, what's going on?

I realize that the most obvious answer is to check my graphics card drivers, and I will try downgrading to an earlier release; but meanwhile note that my *fairly large for one man*-project works flawlessly, and it even uses DirectX shaders! And that I've installed the latest drivers just the week before, when I also reinstalled Windows.

I'm running *Windows Server 2008 R2* with all patches, and vanilla *Visual Studio* with *SP1* - no experimental compilers, or anything.

**EDIT**

- The problem only happens on my machine, if I compile on my machine and run on another the problem is not evident.
- The XAML of the bran new project is simply:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems that there's some kind of problem with the Latest *Catalyst* Driver - 11.8. Installing 11.7 fixed the issue as a workaround, as, well, expected. Mystery kinda solved, except for the **why**...

**So does anyone know why the latest catalysts cause havoc with WPF?**

Comment: Is it happening *only* on your machine?

Comment: "I created a brand new WPF project" - very good idea but do post the XAML to be clear: there are no controls whatsoever here, just the empty Grid?

Comment: @vcjones, yes. My laptop does not have any problems with the *.exe* compiled on my machine.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with your graphics card/chip rather than the code.

Comment: I saw the same problem on a couple of my machines, especially when I move a WPF window from one monitor to the other. I think this is WPF rendering issue. I was lucky that my client haven't seen this issue on their machines yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem with Catalyst 11.8 - see:

http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=279&threadid=154834&enterthread=y

and

[WPF: can't resize window without horrible visual effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450225/wpf-cant-resize-window-without-horrible-visual-effects)

I notice it in VS 2010 as well as our own WPF apps. It's pretty horrible. Seems as though rolling back to Catalyst 11.7 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a hardware problem with your graphics card.